# File.length returns '4096' on directories

Tags: android, file

I am trying to calculate file sizes on my Android phone. Therefore I've written a method which requires the directory the files are in, and an array of the files themselves.

```
public void showFiles(File directory, File[] files) {
    long max = directory.getTotalSpace();
    Log.d(DEBUG, "Directory size: " + Long.toString(max));
    for(int i = 0; i < files.length;  i++) {
        if(!files[i].isDirectory()) {
            Log.d(DEBUG, "File: " + files[i].getName() + " size: " + Long.toString(files[i].length()));
        }else {
            Log.d(DEBUG, "Directory: " + files[i].getName() + " size: " + Long.toString(files[i].length()));
        }
    }
}
```

When calling the method like this:

showFiles(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles());

The output is correct according to **Files** only - but all the **Directories** appear to have a size of 4096 Bytes --> 4 Kilobytes.

How is that possible and what am I doing wrong?

I am looking forward to your response,

Best regards

Here's a snippet of the console output:

```
View: Directory: TuneIn Radio size: 4096
View: File: rmsINFO.txt size: 493
View: Directory: .mmsyscache size: 4096
View: Directory: Playlists size: 4096
View: Directory: PhotoEditor size: 4096
View: File: miniclipId.txt size: 24
```

Comment: You aren't **adding** the file sizes together and storing them into a `total` variable. You need some recursion in case of a directory, to sum its contents. And go deeper in case of subdirectories.

Answer (score 4):

Because Android is unix-based, and 4096 happens to be the default metadata size of a directory. See the [related superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/142893/why-is-the-size-of-a-directory-always-4096-bytes-in-unix)

Comment: Never knew this. Thanks for sharing. +1

Comment: Thanks for the reply, also new for me. I guess I'll have to write some custom recursive method for calculating directory sizes?

Comment: @user2410644 yes, if you wish to have the total size of all the files in a directory, you have to traverse it.